# Rename-LocalUser alternative on PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell

I know PS 4.0 is ancient. But we're using it anyway on some dev servers it is not my decision.

I'd like to know if there's an alternative for Rename-LocalUser which requires 5.1+ Even if it needs calling wmic, I'm unsure if how to use that kind of call, please give me some examples in one or the other way.

Thank you

Comment: The `win32_useraccount` class has a rename method you can call using `Invoke-CimMethod` to rename the account.

Answer (score 0):

[Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) has provided the right answer in his helpful comments on how to approach this on older PowerShell versions.

You can either use [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) to query the local user, and then invoke the [`.Rename(..)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/rename-method-in-class-win32-useraccount):

```
$myAccount = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "name='theAccountIWantToRename'"
$myAccount.Rename('myNewUserName')
```

Or, **recommended use of [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) and [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod)** since `WmiObject` is no longer available in newer PowerShell versions:

```
$myAccount = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount -Filter "name='theAccountIWantToRename'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $myAccount -MethodName Rename -Arguments @{ Name = 'myNewUserName' }
```